# android GLSurfaceView.Renderer: read texture from file, not from resource?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, renderer, glsurfaceview

Well, I've found **plenty** of examples how to read texture from resources in `GLSurfaceView.Renderer::onSurfaceCreated` function. 
What if I want to open file from gallery in my activity? I added function `public int loadTexture (String filename)` to my MyGLRenderer, it looks like that:

```
public int loadTexture (String filename)
{
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    // Read in the resource
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);

    int[] textureId = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures ( 1, textureId, 0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0] );

    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    try{
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    textures[0] = textureId[0];

    return textureId[0];
}
```

And in `MyActivity` class when user opens file from gallery, I call

```
((MyGLSurfaceView)mGLView).getRenderer().loadTexture(filePath);
```

The problem is glGenTextures doesn't generates texture. As I read this is because some **context** is lost. But code in `loadTexture` function doesn't require any context! 
Official documentation tutorial considers only creating texture from resources.
There are many sample projects on github, but they also work with resource's textures uploading in `onSurfaceCreated`.

Please, give me some links on code, where textures are loaded to `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` in runtime. I know Android on quite basic level, so general advices kinda "create new thread and pass gl context" aren't enough. :)

Comment: Russian too?! =) GLSurfaceView works in another thread. You need to load texture only when GL Context was created, so it's very bad to try use Open GL in different threads (more precisely it's difficult).

Comment: @ghostman: so what are the ways to use Open GL in different threads? p.s. Ukrainian :)

Comment: If you have simple scene then just pass all patches into renderer constructor. Or you can make task: specify some interface for loading task and set it from another thread (here you need to sync your threads). Renderer in draw() check whether it has task (tasks) and execute them. Then completed tasks is removed.

Comment: `public synchronized void addTask(final ITask task) { mTasks.add(task); }`

Comment: Or create class scene that will contain all logic and also pass it in constructor or like task.